# RDTSC on Intel Celeron 64-bit Assembly program

Tags: linux, assembly, fasm, rdtsc

I wrote a small random digit program that makes use of RDTSC to give me the randomness. I wrote it on Linux Mint 17 using FASM.

The problem is, it works perfectly on AMD FX 64bit PC but the exact piece of code fail (or hangs) on Intel Celeron netbook (64-bit), both under Windows 8 and Linux Mint (I dual-boot, so I adapted the code for Win 8)

What could be the problem here? This is basically the code;

```
again:
rdtsc
and eax,1111b
cmp eax,10
jae again
;things to do with the random digit
```

I debug it and found that the culprit hides in this part of the code. But I don't see any problem either. It works perfectly on my AMD PC. Is RDTSC disabled by default on Intel CPUs?

Comment: Err... I strongly advise against using `rdtsc` for randomness. One problem it has is that if called in a loop, such a function will give consecutive multiples of some step-value plus an offset (i.e. if it takes 4 bus cycles per loop iteration, you could be getting 1,5,9,13,1,5,9,13,... ). Getting only odd or only even values, or only alternating odd/even values, is not very random at all.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But i don't think there would be a problem with a single digit though. The return in EAX/RAX is good enough for a random single digit. Just a simple program anyway :D

Comment: You would be surprised. If you want something simple yet functional, it smells to me like best for you is a [linear-congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). A simple example: `x_new = 1103515245*x_old + 12345;`

Answer (score 2):

You're essentially reading the number of clock cycles (which is billions per second) and then not exiting the loop unless the last 4 bits of it are < 10. It could be that it just takes a long time for this situation to occur.

If the instruction was disabled your program would have been killed by the OS with an "illegal instruction" error.

Comment: As could happen, for instance, if the loop takes a multiple of 16 bus cycles and the value first seen is `10 <= x <= 15`. [Per comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399947/rdtsc-on-intel-celeron-64-bit-assembly-program#comment45135682_28399947), you'd be getting 13,13,13,13,13,13,13,... without end, for instance.

Comment: James, I don't have that problem with my AMD machine. It randoms just fine for single digits (e,g from 0 to 9). But you could be right in the case of my Celeron netbook, though I doubt it since both CPUs are 64-bit.

Comment: @royalfinest It's all about timing really. There's no guarantee like the person above stated, that your exit condition will ever occur.

Comment: @John. Yes, the problem is with the loop. What confuses is that it never even take a hit. Not even once after running it like a hundred times. Not one hit both in Win 8 and Linux on the same machine (Celeron). But it works flawlessly on my AMD (linux only) - guaranteed every time. So I suspect that it something to do with Intel's RDTSC.

Comment: @royalfinest You could try the rdtscp instruction instead, but it's highly unlikely to be an Intel problem, I'm pretty sure they would have noticed by now

Comment: @james. I didn't mean it was Intel problem :D I meant to say about the difference between AMD and Intel's RDTSC that I am not aware of. But thanks for your replies.

Comment: @royalfinest: RDTSC doesn't measure CPU cycles anymore, and only measures cycles on some normalised clock that isn't effected by things like power management, turbo-boost, etc. Along with that change came CPUs that use a slower normalised clock (e.g. at maybe 1/16th of the CPUs clock speed) and do the equivalent of `TSC += 16;` where your loop can never ever exit regardless of what you do. One simple fix would be to use something like `eax = eax ^ (eax >> 16);` before the `AND`.

Comment: @Brendan. Thanks. That solves it. Only that I still don't understand how it solves the problem.